# Ruby CSV.open need to remove quotes and null characters

Tags: ruby, csv

I am retrieving a large hash of results from a database query and writing them to a csv file. The code block below takes the results and creates the CSV. With the `quote_char:` option it will replace the quotes with NULL characters which I need to properly create the tab-delimited file.

However, the NULL characters are getting converted into "" when they are loaded into their destination so I would like to remove those. If I leave out `quote_char:` every field is double quoted which causes the same result.

How can I remove the NULL characters?

```
begin
    CSV.open("#{file_path}"'file.tab', "wb", Options = {col_sep: "\t", quote_char: "\0"}) do |csv|
        csv << ["Key","channel"]           
        series_1_results.each_hash do |series_1|
         csv << ["#{series_1['key']}","#{series_1['channel']}"]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: To provide more clarity on what I need for the output, it must match the format provided by the 'Windows Formatted Text.txt' in the Save As... menu. That is a tab-delimited format with no quotes in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated in the [csv documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) you have to the set `quote_char` to some character, and this character will **always** be used to *quote* empty fields.

It seems the only solution in this case is to remove used `quote_chars` from the created csv file. You can do it like this:

```
quotedFile = File.read("#{file_path}"'file.tab')
unquotedFile = quotedFile.gsub("\0", "")
File.open("#{file_path}"'unquoted_file.tab',"w") { |file| file.puts replace }
```

I assume here that NULL's are the only escaped fields. If that's not the case use default `quote_char: '"'` and `gsub(',"",', '')` which should handle **almost** all possible cases of fields containing special characters.

But as you note that the results of your query are large it might be more practical to prepare the csv file on your own and avoid processing the outputs twice. You could simply write:

```
File.open("#{file_path}"'unquoted_file.tab',"w") do |file|
    csv.puts ["Key","channel"]     
    series_1_results.each_hash do |series_1|
        csv.puts ["#{series_1['key']},#{series_1['channel']}"]
    end
end
```

Once more, you might need to handle fields with special characters.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Ruby CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) docs, setting `force_quotes: false` in the options seems to work.

```
CSV.open("#{file_path}"'file.tab', "wb", { col_sep: "\t", force_quotes: false }) do |csv|
```

The above does the trick. I'd suggest against setting `quote_char` to `\0` since that doesn't work as expected.

There is one thing to note though. If the field is an empty string `""` - it will force the `quote_char` to be printed into the CSV. But strangely a `nil` value does not. I'd suggest that if at all you're expecting empty strings in the data, you somehow convert them into `nil` when writing to the CSV (maybe using the ActiveSupport `presence` method or anything similar).

Answer (score 1):

First, a tab-separated file is "TSV", vs. a comma-separated file which is "CSV".

Wrapping quotes around fields is necessary any time there could be an occurrence of the field delimiter inside a field.

For instance, how are you going to embed this string in a tab-delimited file?

```
Foo\tbar
```

The `\t` is the representation of an embedded <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The same problem occurs when writing a CSV file with a field containing commas. The field has to be wrapped in double-quotes to delimit the field itself.

Comment: There aren't any instances of the tab character in the data. I am ok with wrapping the fields that have some text quotes because you are right it is better to have it. But then how can I have the NULL fields left with no quotes? If I remove quote_char: all the fields have quotes. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If your input contains any data that needs to be escaped (such as the column separator or the quote character), then you do need to quote your data. Otherwise it cannot be parsed correctly later.

```
CSV.open('test.csv', 'wb', col_sep: "\t") do |csv|
  csv << ["test", "'test'", '"test"', nil, "test\ttest"]
end

puts open('test.csv').read
#test    'test'  """test"""              "test   test"
```

The CSV class won't quote anything unnecessarily (as you can see above). So I'm not sure why you're saying all your fields are being quoted. It could be somehow `force_quotes` is getting set to true somewhere.

If you're **absolutely certain** your data will never contain `\t` or `"`, then the default `quote_char` (`"`) should work just fine. Otherwise, if you want to avoid quoting anything, you'll need to pick another quote character that you're **absolutely certain** won't occur in your data.

```
CSV.open('test.csv', 'wb', col_sep: "\t", quote_char: "|") do |csv|
  csv << ["test", "'test'", nil, '"test"']
end

puts open('test.csv').read
#test    'test'          "test"
```